what does observation space mean in custom gym enviroment?
error -
AssertionError: The obs returned by the step()method length is not same as the observation space length, obs length: 1875, space length: 2

init function :-

def __init__(self,pcl,fcl,plb,ts):
        ...
        self.observation_space = spaces.Tuple((spaces.Discrete(1875), spaces.Discrete(9)))

and the shape of observation returned after every step is (1,1875,9)
for context, I was making a stock environment and the 1875 rows are past candles' data.
what is this observation space ??

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

how do i close this question ? i have solved the problem.
